# MathJax in the list of similar questions (when asking questions)

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, mathjax, similar-questions

As I learned from some more experienced users, there is A-B testing with different display of similar questions (which used to be called "Questions that may already have your answer"). This was announced on Meta StackOverflow: [Duplicate questions display experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384710).
(I am not really sure whether it is still in the testing phase or whether the testing is already over - I only see the "new" version.)

On the sites where MathJax is enabled, it takes a bit of time, but after the MathJax is rendered a single question can take up considerable amount of vertical space. I took an extreme example from [a post pointing out similar problem in the list of the questions on the main site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19650/post-with-many-lines-of-display-math-takes-up-most-of-the-questions-page). Here are some screenshots showing that sometimes it might take quite a lot of scrolling even to get to the second question in the list:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

As far as I can tell, in the "old" version MathJax was not rendered. At least, judging from the screenshot posted in this question: [Why “Search” is inferior to “Ask Question Search”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28841). Still, probably version with MathJax rendered is better, despite taking more space.

I am not really sure whether this can be fixed in a reasonable way. (Although it seems that some fix for big vertical space in the list of the question on the main site [exists in SOUP](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19650/post-with-many-lines-of-display-math-takes-up-most-of-the-questions-page/19793#19793).) And I guess that this is not really a big problem.

Still, I think that it is worth at least mentioning - I am not sure whether MathJax was taken into account when this new feature (or A-B test) was deployed.

Comment: It looks like the system has changed since this bug report so that MathJax is no longer rendered in the "Similar questions" box. I’ve updated the status to status-completed accordingly.